# Prevstate in reactJs

Tags: react-native, expo

This might be a silly question, but how do I get data if I saved the state using prevState.
I am trying to retrieve data from database and send that data through navigation.

```js
const [dataFromDatabase, setDataFromDatabase] = useState('');

    const retrieveFromDatabase = () => {
        db.transaction(
          tx => {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM PreLoveeedTable", 
              [], 
              (_, { rows }) => {     
                console.log("ROWS RETRIEVED");
 // clear data currently stored
                setDataFromDatabase('');
    
                let entries = rows._array;           
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                  setDataFromDatabase(prev => prev + `${entry.id}, ${entry.image}, ${entry.title}, ${entry.price}, ${entry.description}\n
});
              },
              (_, result) => { 
                console.log('SELECT failed!');
                console.log(result);
              } 
            )
          }
        );
      }
```

{dataFromDatabase} will give me the whole entire data in the database.
But wanted to have each entry in the Database. For example entry for title.
I have been stuck on this for a while now and would be appreciated it if i can get a hint.